# Access variable from ASP code behind in ASP page

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I have a Default.aspx, it has it's code behind, Default.cs.aspx.

I have a variable in the Default.cs.aspx

```
public DataSet AllProducts { get; set; }
```

In the Page_Load function I have it getting all these products from a table, assign it to AllProducts, and I use Page.DataBind(); to apparently bind the variable to the page.

However in the page when i do this:

```
<% foreach(DataRow product in AllProducts) { %>
```

it doesn't like AllProducts, doesn't exist in this current context . . . .

Now, I would like two answers.

The first, how do I get access the AllProducts variable?

The second, is it safe to do the data pull inside the aspx page and assign all variables inside the aspx page, if so how?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in the end? Judging by the foreach over your data set, I bet a Repeater or ListView could make things much easier for you.

Comment: sound, well im grabbing all the products out of a database and i want to display them in my own way!

Comment: Maybe it's just a transcription error, but your codebehind should be named Default.aspx.cs not Default.cs.aspx - and be sure to note the difference between codebehind and codefile.

Comment: transcription error, tht really doesnt help though ....

Comment: by the way it doesnt work changing the property to a variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the problem I have been having is to access variables from codefile in the aspx page.
I wasn't forming the syntax correct.

```
<% # AllProducts %>
```

This is what i have been trying

```
<%# AllProducts %>
```

This is what it should have looked like, note the space!

Unfortunately this asks another question, how do I then put that into a variable for the page, because you can't stick that line into the property NavigateUrl in the asp:HyperLink control.

What I'm trying to do now is view the product on another page, so I need to push the productID to that page somehow.